# Error in using Python freeze.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

I want to package my Python file on Ubuntu so I installed python2.7-examples. When I used `python freeze.py my_file.py` I got the following error:

```
Error: needed directory /usr/lib/python2.7/config not found
Use ``/usr/share/doc/python2.7/examples/Tools/freeze/freeze.py -h'' for help
```

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu you have to install the `python2.7-examples` although this still will not fix the issue.

After that you'll need to symlink `/usr/lib/python2.7/config` to the full name of the config in ubuntu which is `/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/`; after I did this I was able to use `freeze.py` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing/ updating python.